# How do I get rid of the xmlns="" from the root node of my XML?

Tags: biztalk

I have a send port with a pipeline with an XML assembler. All my files that it creates look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://LMS.OIv2.Sierra.SierraRouteUpdate">
 <Orders OrderCode="" SCAC="" CarrierName=" />
 <Orders OrderCode="" SCAC="" CarrierName="" />
</Root>
```

How can I get rid of that xmlns attribute from the root node?

Comment: Not adding this as an answer (yet) since I can find a good reference link but I'm pretty sure you can't. Removing the xmlns attribute would make it an invalid xml document that can't be validated against a schema. All of Microsoft's xml serializers will write out a xmlns. Anyone to confirm this?

Comment: http://biztalktalk.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/changing-removing-document-namespaces/#comment-26

This guy says he did it. I just don't get what he is saying. Where would you put that code to make it work?

Comment: Yeah that is a workaround. It takes the xml as string (no longer as an xml document) and does string replaces to remove the namespace reference.

Comment: From the looks of it it goes into a custom component you will have to create and build. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35049/Custom-BizTalk-Pipeline-Encoding-Component

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. See http://www.richardhallgren.com/removing-xml-namespaces-revisit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use-case for this type of message processing is when integrating with legacy systems that do not implement a fully compliant XML parser.  While "in theory", all systems should be able to handle valid XML, back in the real world I find a lot of applications still treat XML in the same way they treat a string or flat-file.

I've updated my [blog post](http://biztalktalk.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/changing-removing-document-namespaces/) to include a sample Visual Studio project, showing the implementation of the code inside a BizTalk pipeline component.  I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 the benefit of the send pipeline component over using schemas with the empty namespace is that the pipeline component can strip xmlns from any outgoing document, and doesn't care whether there are multiple documents which wind up with the same xmlns#root, since the document is now effectively outside of BizTalk's routing mechanism. An XmlReader based solution might also be possible, which would have a lower memory footprint than XmlDocument, for large documents.

Comment: Your component has a TargetNamespace property. What would go there exactly?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Pipeline errors with this component. I can't believe how difficult this is to get an output file in the format I want. I hate biztalk. I could write custom edi code in a fraction of the time it takes me to do the simplest things in biztalk.

Comment: Can you post some details regarding the error(s) you are receiving?  This may be more constructive than ranting about how hard it is to "do the simplest things" in BizTalk.

Comment: This worked for me for the most part. Made a few slight changes. Thanks for the help Brett. I will still rant about how bad biztalk sucks thought because it does. I will never work for a company that uses it again.